# WPF Tabcontrol not showing TabItem content until selection changes

Tags: wpf

I have the following Tabcontrol definition:

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" >
        <TabItem Header="Foo" IsSelected="True" >
            One
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Bar">
            Two
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Smeh">
            Three
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I would expect the "Foo" tab to be selected and the 'One' text to be visible.  This is not the behaviour I'm seeing.  It appears all tabs are unselected and until I click on a different tab (clicking on the one that is supposedly already selected does nothing), then the tab looks selected and shows content.

Does anyone know why the TabControl works like this and how to fix it to work correctly?

Comment: BTW, I have no styles or themes anywhere in the application.

Comment: whats the binding for?

Comment: The binding is so that I have access to the selected Tab in my model.  Each tab is a different set of report parameters and each tab has it's own model that gather parameters and collects the data for the report.  The parent model (where the tabcontrol sits) simply takes the dataset returned from the tabItem model and populates a ReportViewer control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no selected item in the TabControl. If you want to synchronize some model with the selected item, try

```
 <TabControl Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
```

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the same thing (other than the onewaytosource, which shouldn't make a difference other than performance) as my sample code?

Comment: No, the OneWayToSource makes the XAML default value win against the value coming from the model (which is by default null).